# Seasonality in R

Tags: r, time-series

I am looking for a way to determine whether sales data for particular product is seasonal or not in terms of boolean value Yes/No that can be put as a separate column for each product (around 2500).

Data frame looks llike this:

```
Product ID  Date      Sales
X         2015-01       15
Y         2015-01       12 
Z         2015-01       10
X         2015-02       15
Y         2015-02       30
Z         2015-02       NA
and so on
```

I have converted it to time series however I could not make it work for each product.

```
Product ID  2015-01  2015-02
X             15        15
Y             12        30
Z             10        NA
and so on
```

Problem is that I wanted to use the package *greenbrown* and *Seasonality* funcation however it only reads univariate timeseries, all I was able to get is multivariate.

Any ideas how to properly create a timeseries for each of the products and then obtain the seasonality in mentioned format?

Answer (score 0):

Keep it in the original format, and split on product id to select only the particular product.  Select the column using `$` or `[[` operators:

```
library(dplyr)

product_ids = df[["Product ID"]]
product_dfs = split( df, product_ids)

output = lapply( product_dfs, function(product_df){
is_seasonal_tuple =  Seasonality( product_df$Date)
#either return or add to the product df using e.g. mutate
} )
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment! However I am getting an error:
`Error in approx(x[!na], y[!na], xout, ...) : 
  need at least two non-NA values to interpolate`

I have checked my columns and there are no NA values there
`> colSums(!is.na(df)) > 1
       product_id      date       sales 
           TRUE        TRUE        TRUE `

_na.approx_ function from _zoo_ package results in the same error

Comment: Seems like something with the Date parsing to me, but I don't know exactly what form  what the Seasonality function should take.